# How to emulate USB-device as "alive" on VM?

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, emulation, pid

Step by step:

1. My PC has connected printer via USB (I know VID:XXXX and PID:YYYY)
2. I took image of my PC and put inside virtual machine (VMWare)
3. Of course image on my VM doesn't has connected USB-printer (because real printer is connected to my real USB-port on my real PC).
4. One program is running and checking accessibility of printer by check connection with the printer via USB (I don't know how exactly - maybe via WMI, maybe via other way).
5. **Results**:
   **a)** on my real PC this program works
   **b)** on image *doesn't* work

**QUESTION**: is possible to emulate on VM-side that USB-port (VID:XXXX and PID:YYYY) is alive?
Thanks.

**P.S.** I don't want to install USB-redirect-via-TCP or similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the QEMU emulator and to Linux to do that. VMWare probably doesn't support this of thing especially in a Windows environment.

If you are already on Linux, QEMU has hardware emulation of the xHCI and you can assign the host USB devices to KVM (read here: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest).

On Windows, I don't think this will be possible.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
But of course - my question is about Windows-machine.

Comment: What are you trying to carry out in the end?

Comment: If you try to write a program for Windows, why not just test it directly on your Windows machine. From a VM, I don't think you can achieve accessing the USB printer on Windows.